# PHP Problem with array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get one time occurence on my array, with my code I get only first result here is my example code:

```
$arr=array("a","a","b","c","d");
$arrs=array_count_values($arr);
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{
    if($arrs[$arr[$i]]==1)
    {
        //do something...in this example i expect to receive b c and d
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

ciao h

Comment: What do you mean by "get" and "receive"? What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: I mean same thing excuse me my English is really poor..

Comment: "Same thing"? I am asking what you want to do with the result.

Comment: @Tomalak: I use them to exclude values from filering conditions..

Comment: We need more specific information. Can you expand on your code example? What does "do something" mean?

Comment: your code works for me just fine...

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr=array("a","a","b","c","d");
$arrs=array_count_values($arr);
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{
    if($arrs[$arr[$i]]==1)
    {
        echo $arr[$i];
    }
}
```

That should display `bcd`

Comment: Are you working with different code?  The code provided shows `bcd` like you're asking.

Comment: My code is a little more complex but I do not alter contents of '$arr' I simply filter it by 'if' conditions..I think that my '$arr' values are not really clear...

Answer (score 1):

May be you've miss your real results:

```
$arr=array("a","a","b","c","d");
$arrs=array_count_values($arr);
/*
now $arrs is:
array (
  'a' => 2,
  'b' => 1,
  'c' => 1,
  'd' => 1,
)
*/

foreach($arrs as $id => $count){
 if($count==1) {
   // do your code
 }
}

/*******************************************************/
/* usefull version                                     */
/*******************************************************/

$arr=array("a","a","b","c","d");
$arrs=array_count_values($arr);


foreach($arr as $id ){
 if($arrs[$id]==1){ 
   // do your code
   echo "$id is single\n";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Ivan but I need to cycle $arr and during that find the occurence of values inside it so I cannot use your example..

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr=array("a","a","b","c","d");
$result = array();
$doubles = array();
while( !empty( $arr ) ) {
    $value = array_pop( $arr );
    if( !in_array( $value, $arr ) 
            && !in_array( $value, $doubles ) ) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $doubles[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Jochen, your code is really interesting but get others 2 arrays does not help me in this case :(

Comment: then just replace $result[] = $value; with echo $value; and delete the else branch ;)

Comment: excuse me is it correct in your if condition !in_array($value, $arr) the result is in every case false? It's not better to write !in_array($value, $result) thanks again

Comment: the condition !in_array($value, $arr) is true if $value doesn't exists again in the array... in the example above it would be true for the last 4 values from the array

Answer (score 0):

You just need to retrieve any value which only occurs once in the array, right? Try this:

```
$arr=array("a","a","b","c","d");
$arrs=array_count_values($arr);

foreach ($arrs as $uniqueValue => $count)
{
  if($value == 1) {
    echo $uniqueValue; 
  }
}
```

`array_count_values` returns an associative array where the key is the value found and its value is the number of times it occurs in the original array. This loop simply iterates over each unique value found in your array (i.e. the keys from `array_count_values`) and checks if it was only found once (i.e. that key has a value of 1). If it does, it `echo`s out the value. Of course, you probably want to do something a bit more complex with the value, but this works as a placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = 0;
foreach(array("a","a","b","c","d") as $v){
    if($v == 1){$count++;}
}
```

Comment: Just curious, how does that answer the question...?